# Using MySQL, return specific user ID's in a table with duplicate ID's using a second column as the criteria

Tags: mysql

Here's the scenario:

I have a table that looks something like this:

Table name: USER_ACTIVITIES

```
USER_ID | ACTIVITY_CODE
-----------------------
1111    |  013
-----------------------
1111    |  112
-----------------------
2222    |  014
-----------------------
3333    |  028
-----------------------
3333    |  245
-----------------------
3333    |  468
-----------------------
4444    |  079
-----------------------
4444    |  028
-----------------------
5555    |  157
-----------------------
5555    |  523
-----------------------
6666    |  081
-----------------------
7777    |  067
-----------------------
7777    |  624
-----------------------
```

It's an Oracle database using MySQL, and ACTIVITY_CODE is a CHAR field. I need to extract the USER_ID's that have an ACTIVITY_CODE starting with 0, and that have no ACTIVITY_CODE's starting with any other number.

So,

```
WHERE ACTIVITY_CODE LIKE '0%'
```

gives me all the USER_ID's that have an ACTIVITY_CODE starting with 0, but also includes the USER_ID's that have an activity code starting with 0 and other ACTIVITY_CODE's starting with other numbers.

How do I return just the users who only have ACTIVITY_CODE's starting with 0?

I need it to be a single query (subqueries are fine), and I can't create views.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do this via a 'Not in' and using regular expressions.

```
select distinct user_id from user_activities
  where activity_code like '0%'
    and user_id not in (select user_id 
                          from user_activities 
                          where activity_code REGEXP '^[1..9]')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/260974/10)

Putting on my way back hat, you can also simply do a min/max ASCII sort on the activity_code, because you've padded it with 0s.

So this would be the simplest possible query.

```
select user_id from user_activities
  group by user_id
  having min(activity_code) like '0%'
    and max(activity_code) like '0%';
```

[Second SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/260974/14)

Comment: Excellent solutions. I especially like the min/max solution. Thanks for your help. Both solutions worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN to filter out the users that don't match the criteria.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_activities ua1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
           FROM user_activities
           WHERE activity_code NOT LIKE '0%') ua2
ON ua1.user_id = ua2.user_id
WHERE ua1.activity_code LIKE '0%'
AND ua2.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This solution worked for me as well, and mirrors the solution others have come up with in Access, so it's probably the easiest for them to immediately grasp. Thanks for your help.